# Update Chart JS with date range selector

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to update a chart depending on the dates and and shifts selected using ajax. My ajax call returns an array like this:

```
0   
date    "2017-11-20"
shift   "Day Shift"
availability    100
1   
date    "2017-11-21"
shift   "Day Shift"
availability    63.63636363636363
2   
date    "2017-11-22"
shift   "Day Shift"
availability    63.63636363636363
3   
date    "2017-11-23"
shift   "Day Shift"
availability    63.63636363636363
4   
date    "2017-11-24"
shift   "Day Shift"
availability    14.285714285714285
5   
date    "2017-11-20"
shift   "Night Shift"
availability    67.56756756756756
6   
date    "2017-11-21"
shift   "Night Shift"
availability    67.56756756756756
7   
date    "2017-11-22"
shift   "Night Shift"
availability    67.56756756756756
8   
date    "2017-11-23"
shift   "Night Shift"
availability    67.56756756756756
```

my javascript looks like this:

```
// on change event
var request;
$('input').on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('changed');
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }

    var rangeStart = moment($('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').startDate).unix();
    var rangeEnd = moment($('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').endDate).unix();
    var shift = 'all';
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "report_availability.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            rangeStart: rangeStart,
            rangeEnd: rangeEnd,
            shift: shift
        }
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus){
        drawChart(response); 
    });

    request.fail(function (textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {
       console.log('request finished');
    });
});

function drawChart(data) {
    var dates = [];
    var shift1Score = [];
    var shift2Score = [];
    for(var i in data) {
        var found = jQuery.inArray(data[i].date, dates);
        if (found < 0) {
            dates.push(data[i].date);
        }
         if(data[i].shift == 'Day Shift' ) {
            shift1Score.push(data[i].availability);
        } else {
            shift2Score.push(data[i].availability);
        }
     }

    // Destroy the chart if it already exists
    // NOT WORKING
    if(myChart!=null){
        myChart.destroy();
        console.log('destroy');
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.height = 50;
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: "Day Shift",
                backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
                data: shift1Score
            }, {
                label: "Night Shift",
                backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
                data: shift2Score
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });
 }
```

I have 2 problems with this:

problem 1: The chart is not being destroyed so when I redraw it, it just redraws on top of the old chart which causes problems with the hover events. I have tried to use chart.update() to resolve this issue however this seems to just add to the original data instead of replacing it.

EDIT:- I have solved problem 1 by removing the canvas and then creating a new canvas:-

```
$('#myChart').remove();
$('#chartBar').append('<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>');
```

Problem 2: There is more than 2 shifts.. sometime upto 5 and I do not want to hard code all of these. I would like to draw each dataset depending on how many shifts are returned in the array, I am open to changing the array structure in php or javascript but just cannot seem to figure out the correct array structrue or how to build a dynamic dataset array for the chart.

the chart should output like this for 2 shifts:
[image]

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem that you have.

In order to update the graph i am using two functions:

Remove all datasets in current graph:

```
function removeDataset(chart) {
   chart.data.datasets = [];
};
```

Add a new dataset to the graph:

```
function addDataset(chart, name, data, background, border, fill) {
    var newDataset = {
        label: name,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: background,
        borderColor: border,
        fill: fill
    };
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
        newDataset.data.push(data[index]);
    }
    chart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
};
```

So, when i have the ajax done, i use like this:

```
removeDataset(ctx1);
addDataset(ctx1, "Dataset Name", resp.dataset_data_json, "#007bff", "#007bff", true);  
ctx1.update();
```

To declare the graph, i use:

```
var ctx1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas1 = $("#canvas1")[0];   
    canvas1.height = "300";             
    ctx1 = new Chart(canvas1, config_ctx1);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks good but when I have tried it I cannot get it to work, maybe I am just too tired. I will try again later Thanks

Comment: I have tried this again and have it working but only if I do not delete the axis labels. If i delete the axis labels and try to push new ones it seems to merge them all together rather than adding x amount of labels.. do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: I have solved the label problem by pushing each item in the array seperately instead if pushing the whole array.